# Index out range SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I am getting an index out of range error on the following code. The list.datas seems to work on the foreach loop but when i want to access an index list.datas[0] on the HomeView, it is giving me an index out of range error. Here is the code. The only thing I can think of is the api call isn't back in time to access the index, but if thats the case than why can I access it in the foreach loop.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var list = getData()
    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
            HeadView(dataType: list.datas[0])             
                .frame(width:screen.width, height: screen.height / 3)
            
                
            ForEach(list.datas) { i in
                
                NavigationLink(destination: webView(url: i.url).navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)) {
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text(i.title)
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            Text(i.desc)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                        if i.image != "" {
                            KFImage(URL(string:i.image)).resizable()
                                .frame(width:100, height: 70)
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .clipped()
                        }
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }.padding(.vertical,15)
                    .padding(.horizontal,15)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
           
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is the view model that makes the api call

```
class getData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas = [dataType]()
    
    
    init() {
        let source = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=e415be6fa3a9433b9277971bd319b729"
        
        let url = URL(string: source)!
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            let json = try! JSON(data: data!)
            
            for i in json["articles"] {
                let title = i.1["title"].stringValue
                let description = i.1["description"].stringValue
                let url = i.1["url"].stringValue
                let image = i.1["urlToImage"].stringValue
                let id = i.1["publishedAt"].stringValue
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, title: title, desc: description, url: url, image: image))
                }
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I can think of is the api call isn't back in time to access the index

That's exactly the issue. SwiftUI views are rendered frequently, you have to ensure that the view can be rendered with an empty array. So never get an item from an array with index subscription in the body of a view.

A solution is to get the `first` item which returns an optional and assign a default value if the array is empty for example

```
HeadView(dataType: list.datas.first ?? dataType())
```

By the way please name structs and classes with starting uppercase letter.