# Index out of Range, SwiftUI | Append Object with List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've made some progress, I think the issue is that I have a view that is bound with the object I am creating a new of.

[image]

Whenever I clear, remove, delete the items in its itinerary array, I get an index out of range.  Presumably because of the below code:
[image]

So how do I then need to modify THIS function such that the UI can properly handle the deletion of elements without an index out of range?

```
extension Excursion {
    mutating func clear() {
        self.title = ""
        self.date = Date.now
        self.itinerary.removeAll()
    }
}
```

---ORIGINAL ASK---
I'm fairly certain this is a related question: [Index out range SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504562/index-out-range-swiftui)

I essentially followed the scrumdinger sample and built an excursion/itinerary builder instead.  An excursion has a list of itinerary items.  When I add a new excursion to the list of excursions, I get an Index out of Range exception ONLY when I also include a brand new itinerary item with it.  If I do NOT add itinerary items on the initial excursion creation, it works fine and I can add them later in the edit view with no problem.

My assumption was that I had the same issue as the referenced stack overflow, however, I do not have an active view which accesses the list of itinerary items.  There IS a navigationStack that if you flow through the whole thing will get you to a view which does though.

Below is the HomeView which contains the ADD button

```
//
//  ScrumsView.swift
//  OpenAI_iOS_Starter
//
//  Created by David Crook on 6/5/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

@Binding var excursions: [Excursion]
@State private var addExcursion = Excursion.empty
@State private var isPresentingEditView = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
        List($excursions) { $excursion in
            NavigationLink(destination: ExcursionView(excursion: $excursion)){
                ExcursionCardView(excursion: excursion)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Upcoming Excursions")
        .toolbar {
                Button(action: {isPresentingEditView = true}){
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingEditView) {
            NavigationStack {
                ExcursionEditView(excursion: $addExcursion)
                    .navigationTitle("New Excursion")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                isPresentingEditView = false
                                addExcursion = Excursion.empty
                            }
                        }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Add") {
                                isPresentingEditView = false
                                excursions.append(addExcursion)
                                addExcursion = Excursion.empty
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    HomeView(excursions: .constant(Excursion.sampleData))
}
}
```

```
//
//  DetailEditView.swift
//  OpenAI_iOS_Starter
//
//  Created by David Crook on 6/6/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ExcursionEditView: View {
    @Binding var excursion: Excursion
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Excursion Info")) {
                FloatingTextField(title: "Title", text: $excursion.title)

                FloatingDatePicker(title: "Date", date: $excursion.date)
            }

            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    excursion.itinerary.insert(ItineraryItem.empty, at:0)
                    
                }){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        Text("Add Itinerary Item")
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                Text("Swipe to Delete Itinerary Items.")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
            
            ForEach($excursion.itinerary) { item in
                Section(header: Text("Itinerary Item")) {
                    FloatingTextField(title: "Title", text: item.title)
                    FloatingTimePicker(title: "Time", date: item.date)
                    FloatingTextField(title: "Location Name", text: item.location.title)
                    FloatingTextField(title: "Address", text: item.location.address)
                    FloatingTextField(title: "Notes", text: item.notes, axis: .vertical)
                }
            }
            .onDelete{ indexSet in
                excursion.itinerary.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }
        }//END FORM
    }
}

struct ExcursionEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExcursionEditView(excursion: .constant(Excursion.sampleData[0]))
    }
}
```

The full code is located here: https://github.com/drcrook1/OpenAI_iOS_Starter

Let me know in the comments if you want other sections of code.

Thanks for any pointers/tips.

Comment: Where in the code are you getting the error, and what is the full error message?

Comment: I get it on the @main root.  really sucks to get it there.  Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range. I THINK, it has to do with the addExcursion = Excursion.empty and addExcursion having an Itinerary item in it and the edit view still being rendered which contains a LIST.  I THINK I need to convert that LIST to a Foreach with a remove and cleanly kill the addExcursion object.

Comment: I noticed I did not remove the editExcursion by setting it to empty and once I did that, I started getting the same error there as well.

Comment: downloaded your project. I added a new excursion to the list of excursions
 using the `+` button, then added a new itinerary item to it, using the `+ Add Itinerary Item` button,
 and all works well for me, no crash, no errors.
 
I'm on MacOS 13.5, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I fixed it at some point I think later in the day.